# Remove loading spinner in SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, swipeview

I use a SwipeRefreshLayout to reload the content of a listview. 
It works and the onRefreshListener is triggered but the small loading spinner that appears onswipe doesn't want to dismiss after the loading is complete.
Is there a way to make it go ?

**Edit :** fixed SwipeView means SwipeRefreshLayout

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Do you mean `SwipeRefreshLayout`? if so use `SwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false)`

Comment: Yes it was what i meant. I corrected the View name mistake in the op. Thank you your solution works!

Comment: I have this scenario, getting JSON data from server. And how to test if it is already loaded so that SRL can be dismiss - set to false

Answer (score 28):

The correct way of using it is like this:

```
if (swipeLayout.isRefreshing()) {
   swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are using `SwipeRefreshLayout` then use `swipeLayout_object.setRefreshing(false);` for dismiss that loading icon. i.e.

```
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
....


 swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);

 swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {

                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    //Do your task
                    swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                }
            });
}
```

Details available here.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html

Answer (score 6):

For **Kotlin**,

**`SwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false`**

Answer (score 1):

here is complete solution for loading a page and remove loading animation after page is fully loaded.

```
 private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
}
```