# How to Stop Android webView swipeToRefresh loading progressbar?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, webview, pull-to-refresh

Note: This question was already asked  [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467855/how-to-stop-swipetorefresh-progressbar-in-webview) which did not get any answer so I decided to repost it with my code.

I want a webView to refresh the current page when a user pulls down the screen from the top which is working fine. The problem is the loading progress bar isn't stopping after the page has been loaded.

Here's the `MainActivity.java`

```
// Swipe to Refresh
        SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.swipeToRefresh);
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                myWebView.reload(); // refreshes the WebView
            }
        });
    }
@Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (null != swipeLayout && swipeLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        }
```

I have updated the code but it's still loading.

Comment: try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28582653/6834114

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has fixed the issue:

```
        final SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)this.findViewById(R.id.swipeToRefresh);
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                myWebView.reload(); // refreshes the WebView

                if (null != swipeLayout) {
                    swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

more precisely you try code

```
if (swipeLayout.isRefreshing()) {
    swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
}
```

Comment: It's crashing the app without `if (null != swipeLayout && swipeLayout.isRefreshing())`

Answer (score 0):

Set visibility gone to progressBar inside your seOnRefreshListner and stop refreshing swipeLayout after webview is loaded.

```
  swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {  
  @Override public void onRefresh() { // Insert your code here
      ProgressBar. SetVisibility(GONE); 
      if(null != swipeLayout) {
           swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
      }          
      myWebView.reload(); // refreshes the WebView 
  } });
```

Comment: @MaheshGawhne `if(null != swipeLayout) {
                swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }` didn't work.